# Python convert Tuple to Integer

Tags: python, integer, tuples

Is there any function that can convert a tuple into an integer?

Example:

```
input = (1, 3, 7)

output = 137
```

Comment: Does your tuple have only one digit integers? Do you plan hanle tuples like `x = (1, 9, 10, 150)`? If it is, could you specify what output should have? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 25):

```
>>> reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, (1, 2, 3))
123
```

Comment: It's worth noting in Python 3.x, ``reduce()`` is [``functools.reduce()``](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce).

Comment: Also +1. I think this is the most readable, and it's also the fastest (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10062720/722121) for the comparison in timing).

Comment: Arguably the most readable, certainly the most elegant but only the fastest in smaller cases such as this one. The string method is the fastest for large numbers.

Comment: The use of `reduce()` here is essentially a classical method for polynomial factorization, known as [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Answer (score 17):

```
>>> x = (1,3,7)
>>> int(''.join(map(str,x)))
137
```

Comment: This solution is the only one so far that can also handle `x = (1, 9, 10, 15)`. It's not clear if the OP wants to handle them too or not.

Comment: @RikPoggi I would argue that's a pretty unlikely use case, and you don't actually know that that is the correct output for the case. The OP never specified if he wanted x = ``(1, 9, 10, 15)`` to mean ``191015`` or ``15*1+10*10+9*100+1*1000``. Either could be considered valid depending on how you approach the problem. Is he considering the input a set of digits or a set of values split by base?

Comment: hmm yes although he did not specify it as digits i think we can safely assume they are. However, I don't see how you could ever interpret `(1, 9, 10, 15)` as `15*1+10*10+9*100+1*1000`.

Comment: @Lattyware: It's not clear if that might be a use case. I highly doubt that `x = (1, 9, 10, 15)` should give `2015` instead of `191015`, I'd say that it all depends on how that tuple is generated.  Anyway I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062673/python-convert-tuple-to-integer/#comment12880026_10062673) the OP, hoping to get some clearance.

Answer (score 4):

While converting it to a string then to an int works, it's a somewhat hackish method. We have all the information we need to make a number, namely:

- The digits.
- The position of the digits.

As we have this information, we can calculate the number by calculating the value of each unit at each position, then multiplying it up by the digit at said position. We then add together the results and we have our number. This can be done in one line like so:

```
test = (1, 2, 3)
sum((10**pos)*val for pos, val in enumerate(reversed(test)))
```

Let's break this down:

```
>>> list(enumerate(reversed(test)))
[(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

So then, if we multiply it up:

```
>>> list((10**pos)*val for pos, val in enumerate(reversed(test)))
[3, 20, 100]
```

So we just sum to get 123.

Edit: A note on speed:

```
python -m timeit "int(''.join(map(str,(1,2,3))))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.7 usec per loop

python -m timeit 'sum((10**pos)*val for pos, val in enumerate(reversed((1,2,3))))'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.29 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s 'from functools import reduce' 'reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, (1, 2, 3))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.598 usec per loop
```

So if you are going on speed, [Andrey Yazu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10062711/722121) has it. I'm torn as to what I feel is more readable. I always find lambdas ugly somehow, but in general, I think it's still the more readable method.

Edit 2: With very large tuples:

Length 20:

```
python -m timeit -s "x=tuple(list(range(1,10))*2)" "int(''.join(map(str, x)))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.45 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "x=tuple(list(range(1,10))*2)" "sum((10**pos)*val for pos, val in enumerate(reversed(x)))" 
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.7 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "x=tuple(list(range(1,10))*2)" -s 'from functools import reduce' 'reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, x)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.18 usec per loop
```

Length 100:

```
python -m timeit -s "x=tuple(list(range(1,10))*10)" "int(''.join(map(str, x)))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.6 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "x=tuple(list(range(1,10))*10)" "sum((10**pos)*val for pos, val in enumerate(reversed(x)))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 72.9 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "x=tuple(list(range(1,10))*10)" -s 'from functools import reduce' 'reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, x)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.6 usec per loop
```

Here we see that the fastest method is actually the string operation - however, the reality is you are unlikely to be using this outside of the range of, say, 10 digit numbers - where the `reduce()` method still dominates speed-wise. I would also argue that the string method is hackish and less clear to the reader, which would normally be the priority over speed.

Comment: I was just about to post `sum(10**i*x for i,x in enumerate(x[::-1]))` but now I won't haha

Comment: Isn't this answer similar to mine?

Comment: @Abhijit Funny how these things go. I'm not sure if I posted first here, but my answer has plenty of explanation, and using ``reversed()`` is a better option than ``[::-1]`` as it can be faster and is nicer to read.

Comment: Yeah i know, just wanted a shorter answer though, i guess i'll stick to doing things properly even if it makes longer code, especially since `enumerate` and `reversed` have such long names...

Comment: @jamylak With Python, a big part of the aim of the language is to be readable and maintainable, so I'd always advise working more for readable than short, but each to their own.

Comment: If the input tuple is that small it doesn't really matter which solution you choose, so I'd go with the most readable (the string one to me). If you want to time them you should use longer tuples, you might have different results.

Comment: @RikPoggi Updated, I still feel the string method is less readable, personally.

Comment: Nice timings. I think that the string version is the most readable although I like the reduce version the most because it is more mathematical...

Comment: Hang on, the inputs of `range(1,100)` are wrong for every method except the string one as the other two operate on single digits as each element in the list. You should do `range(1,10)*10` instead...

Comment: The sum method only works if every element of the tuple is a single digit.

Comment: @jamylak: You've just noticed that the string solution is more stable than the other ones :)

Comment: OK, I fixed the tests (the results are the same) - I can't really imagine a situation where you would want to do this with multi-digit parts of the tuple, but yes, that is an advantage of the string version (if you want it handled like that).

Comment: I'd like to note that I have an even faster solution :)

Answer (score 1):

this does not convert the integers to strings and concats them:

```
>>> sum([(10 ** i) * input[len(input)-i-1] for i in range(len(input))])
123
```

this is a for-loop in one line.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
In [19]: filter(set('0123456789').__contains__,str((1,2,3)))
Out[19]: '123'
```

I believe this is the simplest solution.

A very fast solution is:

```
plus=ord("0").__add__ # separate out for readability; bound functions are partially-applied functions
int(str(bytearray(map(plus,x)))) #str is necessary
```

How that stacks up against the next-fastest solution:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'x=tuple(list(range(1,10))*10)' 'plus=ord("0").__add__;int(str(bytearray(map(plus,x))))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.7 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "x=tuple(list(range(1,10))*10)" "int(''.join(map(str, x)))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 59 usec per loop
```

Comment: using `__functions__` isn't a good idea, especially when there are other options available, right?

Comment: @0xc0de Why not? `str` is never going to lose the `__contains__` method, and this avoids both (python) function-call, and operator-resolution overheads.

Comment: Note that in Python 3.x, your first example returns ``['1', '2', '3']``, not ``'123'``, and the requested output either way was an int - not a string.

Comment: And with regards to referencing ``__add__()`` a better option is to use ``functools.partial()`` and ``operator.add()`` and do ``plus = partial(add, ord("0"))``.

Comment: @Lattyware In possible what way is it better to use partial? As to the behaviour of the first example, I imagine you can work out how to change it to an int; and Python 3 simply makes some strange changes to the language.

Answer (score 1):

[*@Marcin*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063157/1132524) `bytearray` solution is indeed the fastest one in Python 2.

Following the same line in Python 3 one could do:

```
>>> plus = ord("0").__add__
>>> int(bytes(map(plus, x)))
```

Python 3 handles string and bytes in a different way than Python 2, so in order to understand better the situation I did a little timings. The following are the results I got on my machine.

With Python 2.7 ([code](http://ideone.com/raiFO)):

```
int(str(bytearray(map(plus, x))))           8.40 usec/pass
int(bytearray(map(plus, x)).decode())       9.85 usec/pass
int(''.join(map(str, x)))                   11.97 usec/pass
reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, x)      22.34 usec/pass
```

While with Python 3.2 ([code](http://ideone.com/difhe)):

```
int(bytes(map(plus, x)))                    7.10 usec/pass
int(bytes(map(plus, x)).decode())           7.80 usec/pass
int(bytearray(map(plus,x)).decode())        7.99 usec/pass
int(''.join(map(str, x)))                   17.46 usec/pass
reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, x)      19.03 usec/pass
```

Judge by yourselves :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method to change a tuple into a number is to use string formating.

```
input = (1, 3, 7)
output = int('{}{}{}'.format(input[0], input[1], input[2]))

# TEST
print(output) # 137
print(type(output)) # <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it

```
>>> sum(n*10**i for (i,n) in enumerate(input[::-1]))
137
```

and yet another

```
>>> int(str(input).translate(None,'(,) '))
137
```

Comment: Maybe better: `reverse(input)` instead of `input[::-1]`.