# Generating all combinations using Python

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

Say I've a list with a fixed size and elements.
I wish to create set of all possible combinations of the elements inside the array. How do I achieve this?

In python I've tried to use itertools like this:

```
import itertools
a = [4, 7]
for L in range(0, len(a)+1):
for subset in itertools.combinations(a, L):
    print(subset)
```

Howsoever, this gives me an output`(),(4),(7),(4,7)` as in tuples. I want `4,7,47,74` as my desired output in a list or array(C++) and not to print them after each loop iteration.
I don't know if that's permutation or combination. So kindly bear with me and help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Since you seem to want both `74` and `47`, are you sure you want "combinations" rather than "product" or something else? Do you want the empty "combination" (which is in your tuples but not in your "list")? Do you want a printout or a returned value? If a printout, do you want it printed like a list (with surrounding square brackets)? Why is it that variable `a` has `2` and `3` but your result has `4` and `7`? Please clarify your question.

Comment: What if the elements in `a` have multiple digits, like [123, 45]. What would be the expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python convert Tuple to Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062673/python-convert-tuple-to-integer)

Answer (score 1):

From your sample output (which by the way is not in agreement with your input), it is clear that you don't need `combinations` but `permutations` from `itertools`. You can use `join` to merge your two numbers for printing purpose.

Most importantly, you **should** start your loop over `L` from 1 because you need *at least* length of 1 to generate the permutations other wise you will get empty lists (tuples) as you mentioned in your question.

```
import itertools
a = [4, 7]
lst = []

for L in range(1, len(a)+1):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(a, L):
        lst.append(''.join(str(x) for x in subset))

for l in lst:
    print (l)
```

**Output**

```
4
7
47
74
```

Comment: You probably should not answer a question that has so many issues. The question is not clear in multiple ways--see my comment under the question. You refer to most of these issues yourself in your answer.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Issues as in?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: From the output, I figured out that OP was using the wrong tool. So I thought of clearing this first in addition to guiding the right way (starting from L=1)

Comment: Sorry for the wrong sample array I've declared. It should've been a = [4, 7]. And on the other side, thanks for the answer. But while printing I get the desired results. But if I store them on another list and print the list, I get 4,7,4,7,7,4. How do I fix this? I need 4,7,47,74 in my end result array.

Comment: @TNT.Heisenberg: You are storing or printing the list improperly. It looks like you are printing each character separately. Show us how you are storing and printing and we could explain what is wrong. Also, rather than giving thanks, you should accept this answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.