# How to form a list of numbers from a list of Tuple of digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures, tuples

Following is a output from itertools.permutations function:

```
a =  [(3, 1, 4, 1),
         (3, 1, 1, 4),
         (3, 4, 1, 1),
         (3, 4, 1, 1),
         (3, 1, 1, 4),
         (3, 1, 4, 1),
         (1, 3, 4, 1),
         (1, 3, 1, 4),
         (1, 4, 3, 1),
         (1, 4, 1, 3),
         (1, 1, 3, 4)...]
```

How can I get a list of numbers from the above data in the form:

```
[3141,3114,3411...]
```

Currently,I am only able to get it as:

```
[314131143411...]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python convert Tuple to Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062673/python-convert-tuple-to-integer)

Comment: As the problem statement was too large,I just preferred to mention just the part where I needed help.I can edit the question if that would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
def process_data(data):
    return int(''.join(map(str,data)))

out=[process_data(i) for i in a]
# [3141, 3114, 3411, 3411, 3114, 3141, 1341, 1314, 1431, 1413, 1134,...]
```

Or

```
def process_data(data):
    num=data[0]
    for i in data[1:]:
        num=num*10+i
    return num
out=[process_data(i) for i in a]
# [3141, 3114, 3411, 3411, 3114, 3141, 1341, 1314, 1431, 1413, 1134,...]
```